# Foreign Key Association name In EDMX

Tags: entity-framework, associations, edmx

Foreign key association names generated in EDMX are different than others names. In my EDMX, I could see two flavors of the Names

1. FK_*Allocatio*_EdgeL__367C1819
2. FK_FolderProject

I want all foreign key association names should be in second format. My question is, how to achieve this.

My EDMX is generated from database.